# Can i use googledrive to up- and download sqlite databases from android app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, google-api

So far my application has an sqlite database into which the user can put some items which are stored. 
Is it possible to use GoogleDrive as a location to store this data, so that other users of the application can download the current data or do insertions into it?

I read some documentation about GoogleApiClient and had a look at this https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/ but so far I could not figure out what my problem is exactly...

Comment: If you want to share the database between users, why don't you just host it on a server and load it from there (i.e. have your app connect to that server instead of loading it locally)? That way you won't have to do anything special for (re)storing databases.

Comment: Try dropbox, you can generate a download link for every file and folder you have. Way easier, but a bit slow and expensive in time and resources